# Revisioning with approval

Tags: database-design

I've got a section on my website, which should be edited by users / everyone. Since I want to approve everything first, I was thinking to do it like SO does for edited posts. Anyone has some sources or nice ideas how the database should look like?

Current idea:

Seperate table in my database with every revision for an entry, which has the flag `approved` BOOL. The newest revision which has `approved=true` will be shown as the entry.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for the [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki?)?

Comment: Something like this, yeah, but I want to do it by myself, w/o (sorry for that) looking through hundreds of lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimaryKey | PostID | TIMESTAMP | APPROVED

Your script will display the newest timestamp for PostID that is listed as APPROVED. You can have 1 table that contains all of the revision history differentiated by TIMESTAMP.